# JavaScript not porting into Joomla

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm trying to get JavaScript to work properly in Joomla 1.5 (not upgrading). Well, it's a countdown and it works fine outside of Joomla but once I port it in the countdown doesn't start.

I used Mod HTML, a Joomla extension to add the `<body>` JavaScript, then I added the `<head>` JavaScript directly to the the `<head>` of my template but nothing.

The script demands to save as `.php` for the countdown to work but my Joomla is doing it.
Could it be that Joomla is blocking the JavaScript from communicating to my server?

Links:

- Working correctly [standalone](http://tuphotobooth.com/countdown2.php)
- Not working Joomla [site](http://tuphotobooth.com)

Comment: working correctly standalone http://tuphotobooth.com/countdown2.php not working joomla site http://tuphotobooth.com

Comment: Check your console - you're getting an error on your Joomla site: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'lazyload'`

Comment: removed everything that had to do with the countdown, refreshed and that error keeps popping up and i removed the plug-in so the error went away but it did not fix my problem.

Comment: @noname: Does your console show the line number on which that error's occurring? You really need to fix that.